# I18 Error in rails 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-2, i18n-gem

I have use I18 gem .

I want to translate in dutch so I do the following things

In environment.rb file

```
config.i18n.default_locale = "nl"
```

In Application controller

```
before_filter :set_locale     
def set_locale      
  I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale     
end
```

And create en.yml file with nl.yml file

In en.yml file

```
en:    
  Are_you_sure?: "Are you sure?"
```

and in nl.yml file

```
nl:            
  Are_you_sure?: "Weet je het zeker?"
```

but getting following error

```
syntax error on line 4, col 15: `   Are_you_sure?: "Are you sure?"'
```

Can any one tell me what did I wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mixed "tab" and "spaces". Choose a unic indentation, like

```
en:
  are_you_sure: "Are you sure ?"
  other_thing:
    foo: "Bar"
```

With 2 spaces at each indentation.